# Браузер Google Chrome отправляет в Google данные о поведении пользователей?

Tags: google-chrome

Помню раньше был Google-бар который это делал по-моему.

Comment: Наивно полагать, что корпорация, всеми силами и способами собирающая данные о пользователях будет отказываться от получения данных из своего детища :)  (а ещё говорят, что гугл -  это подразделение ЦРУ)

Comment: Конечно отправляет.

Answer (score 1):

Отправляет или нет, доказать это невозможно. Гугл оставляет за собой право отправлять себе сведения о работе приложения. Т.е. он шифрует и отправляет какие-то сведения к себе на сервера.

Comment: ... и поскольку вряд ли они оставили себе это право по забывчивости, имеет смысл предполагать, что они этим правом пользуются.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно "[Условия предоставления услуг Google Chrome](https://www.google.ru/chrome/browser/privacy/eula_text.html)":

**6. Конфиденциальность и защита личной информации**

6.1. Информация о применяемых Google способах защиты данных содержится в политике конфиденциальности компании на страницах: http://www.google.com/policies/privacy/?hl=ru и http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/ru/privacy.html. Здесь изложены принципы, применяемые Google для обработки личной информации и обеспечения конфиденциальности пользователей при предоставлении Услуг.

6.2. Вы разрешаете использовать свои данные в соответствии с политикой конфиденциальности Google.

а именно:

- details of how you used our service, such as your search queries.
- telephony log information like your phone number, calling-party
  number, forwarding numbers, time and date of calls, duration of
  calls, SMS routing information and types of calls.
- Internet protocol address.
- device event information such as crashes, system activity,
  hardware settings, browser type, browser language, the date and time
  of your request and referral URL.
- cookies that may uniquely identify
  your browser or your Google Account.